# Can't save to mongoDB's database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

While sending a post request i written the following code :

```
 var email = req.body.email ; 
 var newDetails = { email: email };
  Details.create(newDetails);
 console.log(newDetails);
```

while sending the request. The console.log shows me the correct details, 
However in the mongo shell the only collection that exist is "details" and  it's empty .
That's the Mongoose Schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var DetailsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Details", DetailsSchema);
```

I'm using NodeJS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more background information. Do you use a replicaset? What framework/client do you use? What is `Details`? Does your connection work at all? What happens when you insert data through the native client? With the little provided information, no adequate answer is possible imo.

Comment: create is a mongoose function and not a mongo one. this is usually due to the schema not being the same as your "new" object.

Comment: Actually the only collection that exist in the shell is "details"  and not "Details' and it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mongoose Model should be like

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Scheme = mongoose.Schema;

const DetailsSchema = new Scheme({
    email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Details", DetailsSchema);
```

Node js Code should be like

```
var detailsModel = require('../model/Details.js');//path of mongoose model


var detailsData = new detailsModel();
        detailsData.email = req.body.email; 
        detailsData.save(function (err, savedJob) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      } else {
         return res.send(savedJob);
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to write it without the function ?

Comment: No, we need to write the function to save a document in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

To save data in mongoDB's Database
You can use this way

```
var detailsData = new detailsModel();
  detailsData.save()
    .then(business => {
      res.status(200).json({'Details': 'newDetails added successfully'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
```

With this, you can also handle error easily.